# How to count users from same cities in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to count users from same cities. Record is in single table. Here is what i did so far.

```
<?php
$SelectCities = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users ");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectCities)){
                                                
$total_cities       =   mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND user_type='seller' AND user_status = 'Active'");
$total_cities_count =   mysqli_num_rows($total_cities);
?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
<ul class="locat-list">
<li><?php echo $row['city'];?> <span>( <?php echo $total_cities_count; ?> )</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my DB

[My DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4ump.png)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [don't rely on images to show your code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Use a `group by` and then use `count(*)`. e.g. `select count(*), city from users group by city`. That will give you a count of users of the same city (presuming city names are entered the exact same). Not sure what the goal is with the `user_id` query.

Comment: Thank you user3783243. user_id is mistaken by me, i just realized. I have written query as 
$SelectCities = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*), city from users group by city ");
is it correct? 
and then how to call number of users?

Comment: You could get number of users with a `union` or with a second query. You then should just `fetch` the results and output. Use `@` so notifications are sent if directing comments to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it in SQL. Hope that helps:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(userid) 
FROM users 
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY city ASC
```

Comment: Alex, lastly can you please tell, how to call also? I mean how to display number of users?

Comment: It is fixed. Just edited Alex query as

$SelectCities = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT city, COUNT(userId) as totalUsers FROM users GROUP BY city ORDER BY city ASC");

Then Counting as

<?php echo $row["totalUsers"]; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Here, i am count users from city wise in my employee table. using `php pdo`.

```
<?php

// This is a my database connection
$host_name = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'stackoverflow';
$user_name = 'root';
$password = '';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$db_name;", $user_name, $password);

$sql = "SELECT city, COUNT(*) as employee_number FROM employee GROUP BY city"; //This is a query count number of employee city wise
$count_user_cityWise = $conn->prepare($sql);
$count_user_cityWise->execute();

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Number of employee</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            while ($data = $count_user_cityWise->fetch()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $data['city'];
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo $data['employee_number'];
                echo "<td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table
?>
```